# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column data1 while fetcing contacts

Tags: android, android-contacts

Here is my code, it showing java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column data1 exception in logcat. Is my projection is correct? I think something wrong in my projection. Please help. Thanks in advance

```
    public  List<ContactModel> getContacts(Context ctx) {
    List<ContactModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] projection = { ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID };
    ContentResolver cResolver=ctx.getContentResolver();
    ContentProviderClient mCProviderClient = cResolver.acquireContentProviderClient(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
    ArrayList<String> mContactList = null;
    try
    {
        Cursor mCursor = mCProviderClient.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor.getCount() > 0) {
        while (mCursor.moveToNext()) {
            String id = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            if (mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)) > 0) {
                Cursor cursorInfo = ctx.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
                InputStream inputStream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(ctx.getContentResolver(),
                        ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, new Long(id)));
                while (cursorInfo.moveToNext()) {
                    ContactModel info = new ContactModel();
                    info.id = id;

                    list.add(info);
                }

                cursorInfo.close();
            }
        }
        mCursor.close();
    }

    }
    catch (RemoteException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        mContactList = null;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        mContactList = null;
    }

    return list;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The projection is indeed incorrect.

The Contacts DB is organized in three main tables:

1. `Contacts` - each entry represents one contact, and groups together one or more `RawContacts`
2. `RawContacts` - each entry represents data about a contact that was synced in by some `SyncAdapter` (e.g. Whatsapp, Google, Facebook, Viber), this groups multiple Data entries
3. `Data` - The actual data about a contact, emails, phones, etc. each line is a single piece of data that belongs to a single `RawContact`

You're trying to make a query on the `Contacts` table, with projection of fields from the `Data` table, you can't do that.

You can use something like the following code, just convert the `HashMap` to work with your `ContactModel` object:

```
Map<Long, List<String>> contacts = new HashMap<Long, List<String>>();

String[] projection = { Data.CONTACT_ID, Data.DISPLAY_NAME, Data.MIMETYPE, Data.DATA1, Data.DATA2, Data.DATA3 };
String selection = Data.MIMETYPE + " IN ('" + Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "')";
Cursor cur = cr.query(Data.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null);

while (cur != null && cur.moveToNext()) {
    long id = cur.getLong(0);
    String name = cur.getString(1);
    String mime = cur.getString(2); // type of data (e.g. "phone")
    String data = cur.getString(3); // the actual info, e.g. +1-212-555-1234
    int type = cur.getInt(4); // a numeric value representing type: e.g. home / office / personal
    String label = cur.getString(5); // a custom label in case type is "TYPE_CUSTOM"

    String labelStr = Phone.getTypeLabel(getResources(), type, label);
    Log.d(TAG, "got " + id + ", " + name + ", " + kind + " - " + data + " (" + labelStr + ")");

    // add info to existing list if this contact-id was already found, or create a new list in case it's new
    List<String> infos;
    if (contacts.containsKey(id)) {
        infos = contacts.get(id);
    } else {
        infos = new ArrayList<String>();
        infos.add("name = " + name);
        contacts.put(id, infos);
    }
    infos.add(kind + " = " + data + " (" + labelStr + ")");
}
```